# How to create user in postresql version 12?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have loged in postresql as default `postgres` user:

```
psql -U postres
```

and following the official documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-createuser.html  I have type this:

```
create user -d -e --role=myrole -r -s myuser;
```

and nothing happens. Postresql ignores the command.

```
\du
```

does not return `myuser` in user list.
It ignores the command when added any option, only this works:

```
create user myuser;
```

Comment: Try removing the space between 'create' and 'user'.  Like this instead:

createuser -d -e --role=myrole -r -s myuser;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CREATE USER** is a SQL statement that has its own syntax https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createuser.html whereas **createuser** is an executable that has a different syntax: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-createuser.html: you cannot mix them.